# How to set user current location to initialize function in ionic framework

Tags: javascript, google-maps, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

I use ionic map template and now I want to set user current location to center in initialize function in angularjs ;
this my directives.js file codes:

```
angular.module('starter.directives', [])

.directive('map', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      onCreate: '&'
    },
    link: function ($scope, $element, $attr) {
      function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
              center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.07493, -89.381388), //I want to set user current location to center
              zoom: 16,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map($element[0], mapOptions);

            $scope.onCreate({map: map});

            // Stop the side bar from dragging when mousedown/tapdown on the map
            google.maps.event.addDomListener($element[0], 'mousedown', function (e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              return false;
            });
             }

      if (document.readyState === "complete") {
        initialize();
      } else {
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

How I do this work?
thank u?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that could help you:

```js
angular.module('ionic.example', ['ionic'])

    .controller('MapCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading, $compile) {
      function initialize() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.07493,-89.381388);
        
        var mapOptions = {
          center: myLatlng,
          zoom: 16,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
            mapOptions);
```